# How to use the boolean contains(Charsequence s) method in Java?

Tags: java

How do I pass my desired sequence ('admin') to contains method?

```
class containstest
{
    public static void main( String [] args)
    {   
        System.out.println("Enter string");
        Scanner S = new Scanner (System.in);
        String s = S.next();
        char A = 'admin' ;
        boolean flag;
        flag = s.contains(CharSequence A);
        if (flag == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Admin mode");
        }
        else
        {
            system.out.println("customermode");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: This will not compile because of: char A = 'admin';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your code is in the line

```
char A = 'admin' ;
```

You cannot declare a char like that. There are multiple characters in `admin` so you need to use either a **character array** or a **string** to store `admin`.

### By using char array

```
char[] a = {'a', 'd', 'm', 'i', 'n'};
```

I don't think that you will need to use a character array in your problem, but you will need to use a `String`.

### By using string:

```
String a = "admin";
```

After declaring the string you can call the contains method like :

```
flag = s.contains(a);
```

> **Note that char in java is written in `' '` and a String is written in `" "`.**
>  Java documentation strings :
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 1):

`char` type means 1 character. Therefore line `char A = 'admin' ;` is incorrect. If you want to work with string literal you have to write

```
String a = "admin";
```

Please pay attention on:

- `String` - is the type of variable.
- double quotes instead of apostrophe that you used.

Please note also that in Java we start variable names from small letter. This is not mandatory, it is convention only, but a well-known convention.

Answer (score 0):

It shuold be `s.contains("admin")`.

"admin" (not 'admin') is a `String`, not a character, so you can't assign 'admin' to a char variable, and you can't use single quote for more than one character.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than inputting the value of the char A, you are declaring a new variable when invoking the method, when you call `s.contains(Char A)`.
The *correct* one should be:

```
s.contains("string sequence here")
```

For your code though, you should consider changing the `char A` to `String A`.

Comment: As a sidenote, the `char A` would be better of as `char a`, as per naming conventions.